# How to define default values for a JSX attribute so vscode can display them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want vs code to display the default values for a component attribute/property as a way to provide feedback to the developer at the moment they'll provide a value, instead of remembering or looking at component's source code for it's possible values. So if one of it's properties is size then it has to display small, normal and large.
So how do i accomplish this using js/react?
Please forgive my ignorance since i'm really new at the react ecosystem.

Comment: You want to use typescript in your react app. It will provide autocompletion for typed values.

Comment: Well at least i'm less ignorance now, i might try TypeScript. Thanks guys.

Answer (score -1):

What you require is currently not implemented in JSDoc or in TypeScript. You can follow the related issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16665